# Boosting algorithm realization in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, boosting

Using `sklearn` one can construct `Bagging` algorithm for non-trees estimator (for example, for SVC). But there is no `Boosting` realization in `sklearn` or in any other well known packages. Am I missing something and there is some existing Boosting algorithm with ability to select any other estimators other than trees in standard approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AdaBoostClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html) is what you are looking for. [Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#adaboost) is a complete list of ensemble algorithms implemented in `sklearn`.